# Centered image in desktop/tablet/mobile website

Tags: css, web, resizable

Good morning,

Sorry to bother with basic question, but I need to make plain design with solid color on the background and one graphic on dead centre. What I made is working on desktop PCs but, unfortunatelly, graphic is cutted when I'm previeving on my phone or tablet.

What I made:

```
body {
background-color: #000;
background-image: url(static/images/coming-background.jpg);
background-position: center center;
background-size: fixed;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Setting `background-size` property to `inherit` or `initial` works for me:

```
body {
    background-color: #000;
    background-image: url(static/images/coming-background.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: inherit;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/svitch/pen/RLvbEp)

Comment: Thank you svitch for your answer but it is not working for me, maybe because of the size of graphics (1232x569)?

Comment: you may set background-size to **contain**; if you need it to fit within screen

Comment: Or background-size: **50%**; to be half of original image size (should be 616x285)

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not working for me. I tried with `@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1199px) {` but still my image is cutted. I wonder why since my dreamweaver preview is showing me that it should be all OK.

Comment: do you have a live preview of that page?

Comment: Here in my pen: https://codepen.io/svitch/pen/RLvbEp - image is all inside the screen, no circle cropped

Comment: alternatively, you can place background `<div>` block with limited max-width and height, f.ex. 640x480, with image background, using `background-size: contain`